# use of CLLocationManager class in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can we use CLLocationManager class to determine the position of the user in an iPad app  or is it used only for iPhones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works fine on iPads.  However, the location accuracy is based on WiFi only unless it is a 3G iPad which has GPS.

Comment: Thanks dude....can u tell me that can we determine the location in an iPod touch also because it also supports WiFi using CLLocationManager and how accurate will it be?

Comment: It will vary significantly depending on how many wifi spots can be seen by the device.  See [this blogpost](http://www.jeremyjohnstone.com/blog/2010-04-08-ipad-geo-location-accuracy.html).  Location accuracy on an iPod Touch would be the same as a WiFi only iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the information.It is quite helpful for me.Is there any refrence or some sample app available ...it will be quite helpful.thx

Comment: [Searching](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=CLLocationManager+OR+CoreLocation+tutorial+OR+example+iphone&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) finds several examples and tutorials.